# Priority Queue Poll() returns the incorrect object

Tags: java, priority-queue, dijkstra

Im doing Dijkstra's algorithm, so I am using a priority queue.

```
private static class Node implements Comparable<Node>{
    String name;
    ArrayList<Edge> connections;
    int weight;
    Node parent;

    public Node(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        parent = null;
        connections = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addConnection(Node node, int weight){
        if(node == null)
            return;
        Edge edge = new Edge(this, node, weight);
        connections.add(edge);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Node o) {
        if(this.weight - o.weight == 0)
            return this.name.compareTo(o.name);
        return this.weight - o.weight;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + name + ": " + weight;
    }

}

private static class Edge {
    Node origin;
    Node destiny;
    int weight;

    public Edge(Node origin, Node destiny, int weight) {
        this.origin = origin;
        this.destiny = destiny;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "<" + origin.name + "," + destiny.name + ": " + weight + ">";
    }
}
```

And here is Dijkstra's algorithm:

```
PriorityQueue<Node> pq = new PriorityQueue<>();
    for(Node node : graph)
        pq.offer(node);

    while(!pq.isEmpty()){
        Node actualNode = pq.poll();
        for(Edge connection : actualNode.connections) {
            if(connection.destiny.weight > actualNode.weight + connection.weight) {
                connection.destiny.weight = actualNode.weight + connection.weight;
                connection.destiny.parent = actualNode;
            }
        }
        if(actualNode.weight == Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            actualNode.weight = -1;
    }
```

As far as I know the poll() method from the priority queue should allways return the node with the lowest weight because of my comparable, right? but when I run it, it just pulls the 2nd node in the queue and not the lowest one.
I am guessing its not working because the queue doesnt realize that I updated the value of the queue but Im not sure. Anyone know how to  fix?

Comment: "I am guessing its not working because the queue doesnt realize that I updated the value of the queue" <-- Yes. To update the queue, you can remove the element from it, update the element, then add it back again.

Comment: Please post hard-coded test data that show the problem stated _"Queue Poll() returns the incorrect object"_ (`Dijkstra's algorithm` is not needed to show the problem. Just add node to the queue and `poll` them).